# merge multiple images to create profile image in android

Tags: android

I am working in chat app, it allow group chat, in messenger that chat image looks like that

[image]

does anyone know any library or sdk that can take one or two images and if one draw a circle and if two draw something like what is found in the images

and if no, how to do it ?

Comment: From what I see it is item that has `ImageView` and a `TextView`. They might use **a shape circle drawable xml as background** for `ImageView`. And to combine them as shown in the picture, they sure using a **frameLayout** that let you stack views over views.

Comment: Library requests are off-topic. You can ask on [softwarerecs.se] instead. Even if this was a question how to make that layout it's far too broad. I highly suggest you re-read [ask].